# EWS API FindItems by Id

Tags: exchangewebservices

I want get an item by Id. this is my code but I don't know why it's not work!

```
AlternateId ewsID = ExchangeServiceManagement.ConvertOWAid(
                exchangeService, letterRequestData.Id, letterRequestData.FromSender);

ItemView itemView = new ItemView(1);
            FindItemsResults<Item> findItemsResults = exchangeService.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, "id:" + ewsID, itemView);


internal static AlternateId ConvertOWAid(ExchangeService esb, String oiOWAID, String emEmailAddress)
        {
            AlternateId alternateId = new AlternateId();
            alternateId.Format = IdFormat.OwaId;
            alternateId.UniqueId = oiOWAID;
            alternateId.Mailbox = emEmailAddress;

            AlternateId resultAlternateId = (AlternateId)esb.ConvertId(alternateId, IdFormat.EwsId);

            return resultAlternateId;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the EWS Managed API and follow the 'tutorials' on msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/dd633693(v=exchg.80).aspx